# How to store hardcoded encryption master key in android?

Tags: android, encryption, key, android-room, sqlcipher

I'm building an app that uses Room and I want to encrypt the db using SQLCipher which needs a master key to encrypt/decrypt the db. I don't want to get the master key from the user, I want to use 1 master key and store it on the device but as far as I know hardcoding the key is not secure. So I want a way to store the key securly on the app to use it with SQLCipher.

Comment: [This sample project](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-room/-/tree/v0.6/ToDoGen) demonstrates generating a passphrase, then storing it in a file encrypted using a `KeyStore`-based encryption key (via `androidx.security` and its `EncryptedFile` class).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [library](https://github.com/yakivmospan/scytale) to secure your data using android keystore system.
You can generate key in your app as:

```
String keyAlias = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID;
// Create and save key
Store store = new Store(FieldForceApplication.getContext());
if (!store.hasKey(keyAlias)) {
    SecretKey key = store.generateSymmetricKey(keyAlias, null);
}
```

And then get key using keyAlias(In my case applicationId), you can set any string.

```
SecretKey key = store.getSymmetricKey(keyAlias, null);
```

After getting key you can encrypt or decrypt data as:

```
Crypto crypto = new Crypto(Options.TRANSFORMATION_SYMMETRIC);
String encryptedData = crypto.encrypt(rawText, key);

String decryptedData = crypto.decrypt(rawText, key);
```